# Undefined variables, after if

Tags: python

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWL6l.png)

In def __ init __ I put token and channel_id and in def main I used them in if command and both of them created an error that they are undefined. How to change this? Is there a way to recall them in def main?

```py
import requests
import sys

class Bonk:

    def __init__(self, token, channel_id, message):
        self.token = token
        self.channel_id = channel_id
        self.message = message
        self.headers = {'Authorization': token}

    def _generate_message(self, m1):
        return m1

    def execute(self):
        return requests.post(f'https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/{self.channel_id}/messages', headers=self.headers, json={'content': self._generate_message(self.message)})

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 99999:
        print(f'Usage: py {sys.argv[0]} <TOKEN> <CHANNEL ID> "MESSAGE"')
        sys.exit()

    if token == 0:
        print('token')
        token = input()

    if channel_id == 0:
        print('channel_id')
        channel_id = input()

    message = 0
    if message == 0:
        print('message')
        message = input()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.  Maybe if you clued us in as to the variables you are talking about, and provided a clearer description of the problem you are having, someone might be able to help you.

Comment: @CryptoFool: The problem that the OP has is quite clear. The problem *we* have is to persuade the OP to reveal enough details to make it clear to everyone else.

Comment: Well, there *is* no "token" defined in `main`, and not a "channel_id" either. Were you expecting these names to refer to the attributes of a `Bonk` instance that you never created? Perhaps you should be looking for an introduction to Python.

Comment: All your variables are inside functions. This is a good start. Unfortunately variables inside functions are in different scopes, so are created inside the functions and deleted when the function exits. Perhaps you meant to pass variables as parameters to functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

is used to launch the main() function when you excecute the script from command line

Now imagine launching the function from shell, you give no args to the function, it can't define token and channel_id by itslef

Your class is never read if you don't instanciate it

You need to have something like

```
bonk = Bonk(token=1234,channel_id=5678,message='message')
```

And then you can use

```
if bonk.token == 0:
   your code
```